# Fix "SharedArrayBuffer is not defined" on local http.server

Tags: python, http.server

I use `python3 -m http.server --bind localhost` to quickly host local versions of web content for testing.

I was using this to host a web version of a game I was working on and ran into this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined

The engine I'm using [has advice for this error](https://github.com/Davidobot/love.js):

> Enable the following HTML response headers on the website you're hosting your project on:
>
> - Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
> - Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp

But I don't understand how to set these headers. Do I need to implement my own subclass of BaseHTTPRequestHandler (and how)? Or do I call `send_header` on... something?

Comment: Can you share which browser you are using? and I believe you can go console and do enable them. Most of the browsers support this out of the box.

Comment: I'm using Chrome.